# How to call on Functions, within a Function with respect to strings?

Tags: c

```
float fkgrade(const char str[]) { 
    float words, sentences, syllables, level;
    words = wordCount(str[]);
    sentences = sentCount(str[]);
    syllables = sylCount(str[]);
    level = 0.39*(words/sentences) + 11.8*(syllables/words) - 15.59;
    return level;
}

int main() {
    char plato[] = "He who is the real tyrant...";
    float out = fkgrade(plato);
    printf("> Reading Level = %f\n", out);
}
```

I have these three working (tested individually) functions above the fkgrade and main functions

```
float wordCount(const char str[]) {
float sentCount(const char str[]) {
float sylCount(const char str[]) {
```

Yet when I try to call upon them in the fkgrade function, I keep getting

```
/tmp/tmpqvmtuopy.c:95:27: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
   95 |     words = wordCount(str[]);
      |                           ^
```

for all 3 calls. I'm not sure if str[] is the right way to call it and I've tried many other ways but it hasn't worked. I am a beginner and if anyone has any solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't you just do this `wordCount(str);`

Comment: Please change them to, eg, `words = wordCount(str);`

Comment: Yes, changing it to wordCount(str) worked, I am shocked I didn't think of that on my own. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is - exactly as your compiler says - in line `words = wordCount(str[]);`.

While passing a whole array into a function - you have to pass just a name of your already initialised array.
Your line of code should look like this:

```
words = wordCount(str);
```

But beware of a similar situation which works differently - when you want to pass char from an array into function that wants char on the start.
In that case you would have to do it like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void disp( char ch)
{
   printf("%c ", ch);
}
int main()
{
   char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
   for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
   {
       /* I’m passing each element one by one using subscript*/
       disp (arr[x]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```